Multiple i.i.d. transistors are chosen one at a time until one's lifetime over s hours. Are N and Xn independent random variables?
Sorry I cannot type the whole question in the Title. The whole question is as follows:
Suppose that the lifetimes of a certain brand of transistor are identically distributed and independent random variables with distribution function $F$. These transistors are randomly selected, one at a time, and their lifetimes are measured. Let the $N$th be the first transistor that will last longer than s hours. Let $X_N$ be the lifetime of this transistor. Are $N$ and $X_N$ independent random variables?
My idea is:
$$\Pr(N=n) = F(s)^{n-1}*(1-F(s))$$
$$\Pr(X_N=x) = P(X_N=x)$$
but
$$\Pr(N=n, X_N=x) = F(s)^{n-1}*P(X_N=x)$$
thus they are not independent. But the answer given in the textbook said they are independent. Hope someone could tell me what's wrong. Thank you.

Assuming $x>s$ we have $P[X_N=x] = P[X_n=x|X_n>s]= \frac{P[X_n=x]}{P[X_n>s]}$. If $x\leq s$ then $P[X_N=x]=0$.

Considering ${X_N=x}$ is useful if $X_i$ are discrete, but generally it may be better to consider ${N=n}$ and ${X_N>t}$ for all $n,t$.
